# Different CURL versions for root and user

Tags: php, curl, centos, libcurl

OS: CentOS7;

Issue: After CURL upgrade from 7.29 to .7.67(build from source) curl -V shows different versions for root and user; PHP shows 7.29;

ROOT

[root@serv curl-7.67.0]# curl -V

**curl 7.29.0** (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.29.0 NSS/3.53.1 zlib/1.2.7 libidn/1.28 libssh2/1.8.0
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtsp scp sftp smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: AsynchDNS GSS-Negotiate IDN IPv6 Largefile NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz unix-sockets

USER

[user@serv curl-7.67.0]$ curl -V

**curl 7.67.0** (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.67.0 OpenSSL/1.0.2k-fips zlib/1.2.7
Release-Date: 2019-11-06
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtsp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: AsynchDNS HTTPS-proxy IPv6 Largefile libz NTLM NTLM_WB SSL UnixSockets

Comment: Do `which curl`; you presumably have two versions installed.

Comment: That's indeed true: for user -> /usr/local/bin/curl; for root -> /bin/curl. Question is how to get things back on track.